# How to print table data between time limit in Laravel 5.6?

Tags: php, laravel-5

In my laravel application I have following table called `schools` like this:

```
id   name   project   type   created_at   updated_at
1    gfr    bottle    hard   2018-06-25   2018-06-25
2    kio    book      soft   2018-06-27   2018-06-27
3    nhj    vehicle   hard   2018-06-27   2018-06-27
1    nhy    bottle    hard   2018-06-28   2018-06-28
1    gfr    book      soft   2018-06-28   2018-06-28
```

Now I need a controller function to print `name`,`project`, and `type` between `2018-06-27` and `2018-06-28` and I have the following controller function

```
$datas = Schools::orderBy('id','desc')->get();
```

Then how can I filter time limit here?

Comment: Why do you have duplicate id ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the whereBetween function, which will search where a column value is between two specified values:

```
$datas = Schools::orderBy('id','desc')
    ->whereBetween('created_at', ['2018-06-27', '2018-06-28'])
    ->get()
```